# SELECT SUM and remove similar rows

Tags: mysql, where, exists

```
SELECT 
SUM(coins.available_supply * hist_all.price) AS market_cap_usd_all 
FROM coins
    LEFT JOIN hist_all ON coins.id = hist_all.coins_id
    WHERE hist_all.price != 0
AND (hist_all.second_coin = 'USD' or hist_all.second_coin = 'USDT');
```

I try get sum `market_cap_usd_all`, but in my table are rows with `USD` and `USDT`:

[image]

My query should like this:

if exists row `second_coin = USD`, DON'T GET this same row with 'USDT', but if don't exists row with `second_coin = USD` check if it exists row with `second_coin = USDT` and get him. So the table should like this:

[image]

I don't know how write query with `WHERE IF` I tried this:

```
... WHERE IF (hist_all.second_coin = 'USD', hist_all.second_coin = 'USD', hist_all.second_coin = 'USDT')
```

but it still sums all rows, both from USD and USDT.

Comment: Trying to understand here.  Are you just trying to get a sum of market_cap_usd_all for anything that is USD only?  Or are you trying to get the total of all USD and USDT?

Comment: @ShooterMcGavin, no, I try get `market_cap_usd_all` from `USD` and `USDT`, BUT IF EXIST USD, CAN NOT DOWNLOAD VALUE WITH USDT. For example I have 2 same records: `first_coin = BTC` with USD and USDT, in this example I need get only value from `market_cap_usd_all` where `second_coin = USD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join or a correlated subquery (with `EXISTS), in order to compare rows:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(c.available_supply * h.price) AS market_cap_usd_all 
FROM coins AS c
    JOIN hist_all AS h
    ON c.id = h.coins_id
WHERE h.price <> 0
  AND ( h.second_coin = 'USD' 
     OR 
        h.second_coin = 'USDT'
        AND NOT EXISTS
            ( SELECT 1
              FROM hist_all AS hi
              WHERE hi.first_coin = h.first_coin
                AND hi.second_coin = 'USD'
            )
      ) ;
```